# How can I plot 2 LM lines using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(output1, aes(Year, SuPDem, color = as.factor(v2x_regime))) +
  geom_line(size = 0.6) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orange", "blue"), labels = c("democracies","autocracies"))+
theme_minimal(base_size = 5)
```

My df is:

| v2x_regime | Year | SuPDem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1990 | -0.581147 |
| 0 | 1991 | -1.581147 |
| 0 | 1992 | 2.371147 |
| 1 | 1990 | -0.581147 |
| 1 | 1991 | -0.471147 |
| 1 | 1992 | -0.601147 |

This works perfectly in generating line graphs. However, I would like to create LM for both democracies and autocracies. Since, I do not plot two different columns, but instead I have a binary variable (v2x_regime) where 0 means autocracies, 1 means democracies it seems more complicated. How can I plor LM for both democracies and autocracies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you be looking for something like this? I only added the `geom_smooth()` function to what you already have and gave it the the `method = "lm"` argument. I got the two separate `LM` lines added to your graph.

**LM lines on plot lines:**

```
ggplot(output1, aes(Year, SuPDem, color = as.factor(v2x_regime))) +
    geom_line(size = 0.6) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("orange", "blue"), labels = c("democracies","autocracies"))+
    theme_minimal(base_size = 5)+
    geom_smooth(method = "lm",se=FALSE)
```

**LM lines on plots:**

```
ggplot(output1, aes(Year, SuPDem, color = as.factor(v2x_regime))) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("orange", "blue"), labels = c("democracies","autocracies"))+
    theme_minimal(base_size = 5)+
    geom_smooth(method = "lm",se=FALSE)
```

Comment: This is amazing, LM works perfectly but I would like to have the linear lines upon the points. How can I modify this according to what I said? Many thank!

Comment: @user19562955 like my second answer?

Comment: Exactly, and can I also compute the correlation between those two lines?